# DB Cursor fetching in Web Applications

Tags: php, sql, mysql, pdo, database

I never understood this: in web development whe[*n|re*] does it make sense to fetch results one by one?

I mean, why should I use [`PDOStatement->fetch*()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) when I can use [`PDOStatement->fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770630/pdofetchall-vs-pdofetch-in-a-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchAll()` will fetch all the results into one big array.

With very large result sets, it could exceed the PHP script's memory limit.

A pure `fetch()` will fetch each record one by one, neutralizing that danger.

That's the only reason not to use `fetchAll()` I can think of.

Comment: Sure, but we usually don't emit SQL statements like `SELECT * FROM oneMillionRowsTable` without a limit clause, at least I've never seen a query like that in web applications.

Comment: @Alix neither have I, but it is not entirely unthinkable to happen. I prefer the `fetch` variant out of a general sense of "My PHP script's memory is more limited than that of the mySQL server". It could be, though, that `fetchAll` is faster because it talks to the server only once - I don't know, I've never measured it.