# MySQLi, prepared statements and associative arrays

Tags: php

Im switching from good ol' `MySQL` to `MySQLi` (late bloomer, I know) and have chosen `MySQLi` over `PDO`.

Firstly, I like associative arrays `(eg: $db_data['whatever_field'])`, so I cannot use prepared statements because that doesnt return associative arrays (by default / without workarounds).

So I have to manually prepare my `MySQLi` statements myself, eg:

```
'SELECT * FROM admin_users WHERE email='. $mysqli->real_escape_string($_COOKIE['admin']['email']) .' AND password='. $mysqli->real_escape_string($_COOKIE['admin']['password']);
```

As you can imagine, this could get tiresome! Is there a short `$mysqli->real_escape_string()` or what do you guys do?

Comment: MySQLi generally requires slightly more verbose code than PDO and considerably more verbose than `mysql_*()`.  Don't worry about the extra code - do what you need to do to pull associative arrays out of a prepared statement, because as you are doing it, you are not getting the primary security benefit of parameterized queries.

Comment: I use PDO and don't worry about escaping it.

Comment: What do you mean it wont return an array? did you try [`mysqli_stmt::get_result`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) and [`mysqli_result::fetch_assoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)? Also im curious at to why you chose `Mysqli` over `PDO`... `PDO` is som much easier to work with in a variety of ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not going to use Mysqli over PDO under my watch son!

> Firstly, I like associative arrays (eg: $db_data['whatever_field']), so I cannot use prepared statements because that doesnt return associative arrays (by default / without workarounds).

That's a bad excuse.

```
PDOStatement::fetch
```

accept as first parameter the fetch style which can be set to `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`.

Also,

```
 PDO::setAttribute
```

makes you able to choose your default fetch style, in particular setting `PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE` to `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`.

Reference:

- [PDOStatement::fetch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)
- [PDO::setAttribute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php)

Comment: Actually hes saying he WANTS assoc back from his executions and hes trying to figure out how to do it with mysqli... +1 because i support your effort to convert him to PDO like a sane person ;-)

Comment: ok, so youve converted me. PDO it is. Now, do I use fetchAll and iterate through the array manually or just use fetch in a while loop? According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770630/pdofetchall-vs-pdofetch-in-a-loop) for another question. fetchAll is faster but uses significantly more memory where fetch is marginally slower and uses far less memory. Sounds like fetch is the winner?

Comment: @SupaMonkey, I have seen a lot of `while ($a = $query->fetch())` but I think it's really up to you. In my personal preferences I think "`fetch`-method" is cleaner.

Comment: @Supa: It depends.. you can run into the memory problem real quick with fetch all if you have a ton of records. If I have even the slightest reason to beleive at some point in the future ill be dealing with a large number of result i use `while`/`fetch`.

Comment: Maybe you guys can help me with another question in the PDO line; Im starting to pull out my hair and wish I stuck with MySQLi! [Check it here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999287/php-pdo-issue-with-sanitised-order-by-fields)

Answer (score 1):

If you prepare statements you don't need escaping, that's one of the main purposes of preparing statements.

I support the explanation by Jeffrey of why use PDO, and I also want to contribute that mysqli is a weird library and really hard to test if you ever have to. The way you bind variables by reference is quite not easy on the eyes.
I personally recommend you reconsider your choice. Hopefully one day we deprecate mysql and mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

There's a function named `fetch_assoc`.
Further reading from php manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

> mysqli_result::fetch_assoc -- mysqli_fetch_assoc — Fetch a result row
>   as an associative array