# Basic ranking of MySQL data and printing result with php

Tags: php, mysql, ranking

I have a table which in which I want to rank rows where one of the columns equals a value I have defined.

For example in this table I want to get all rows where Col1 = a, then find what is the rank of the row in which Col3 = Ross (ranked by score in Col2).

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3
------------------
a    | 10   | John
a    | 6    | Nick
a    | 8    | Ross
a    | 2    | Tim
a    | 4    | Paul
b    | 9    | John
b    | 3    | Nick
b    | 5    | Ross
b    | 7    | Tim
b    | 1    | Paul
```

Ultimately I want to calculate this:

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Rank
-------------------------
a    | 10   | John | 1
a    | 8    | Ross | 2
a    | 6    | Nick | 3
a    | 4    | Paul | 4
a    | 2    | Tim  | 5
```

And print the result "2".

I can sort the table with this query, but dont; know how to then print the result I need (with php).

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM exampleTable WHERE Col1 = a order by Col2 DESC";
```

Comment: Do you have a primary key that you are not showing here? Or do you want to sort by row identifier?

Comment: No I don't - should I add one?

Comment: You..don't..have..a..primary..key..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
"SET @rank=0; SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, @rank:=@rank+1 AS Rank FROM exampleTable WHERE Col1 = 'a' order by Col2 DESC) AS t"
```

Here is a [test run](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a355b/6) that shows it working.

If you want to find Ross's rank you can run the query with `WHERE Col3 = 'Ross'` added and only the rank column selected, as demonstrated [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a355b/5)

Comment: That's exactly the query I need - how do I print the result with PHP?

Comment: First establish a connection using `mysqli_connect`, then use `mysqli_query(etc.)` to query and retrieve a resource, then use its fetch array method to return the result set as an array. http://www.phphaven.com/article.php?id=65 is a short tutorial on using mysqli.

Comment: I am getting an 'error in the SQL syntax'. I think it is because of the semi-colon in the query, but I can't figure out how to delimit it. Any suggestions?

Comment: @JohnCatterfeld It should also say where the error is occurring. `error in the SQL syntax near ...`

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT Rank FROM (SELECT *, @rank:=@rank+1 AS Rank FROM exampleTable WHERE Col1 ' at line 119

Comment: @JohnCatterfeld Try using mysqli_multi_query instead. Same syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your help - this what I got to work (table and columns have different names) `select * from (select @rownum:=@rownum+1 Rank, p.* from events p, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r WHERE SportID = 1 order by TotalPts desc) Rank_events where CompetitorID = 5`

Comment: This solution is deprecated. You can use the RANK() function now (since 8.0) (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59883677/1557649 )

Answer (score 1):

with pdo

first create pdo connection by

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=UTF-8', 
       'username', 'password', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, 
          PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
```

than use like that

```
$query= $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM exampleTable WHERE Col1 = a order by Col2 DESC");

$query->execute();
$article=$query->fetchAll(pdo::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

reason i am using the fetchAll not the loop is its faster if memory does matter than use the loop

[PDO::fetchAll vs. PDO::fetch in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770630/pdofetchall-vs-pdofetch-in-a-loop)

Answer (score 0):

To get the ranking of results, you can use the [MySQL RANK() function](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-rank-function/) since MySQL 8.0.

Your query then looks like this:

```
$query = "SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Col2 DESC) myRank FROM exampleTable WHERE Col1 = 'a'";
```