# PHP PDO method to fetch simple list of matched elements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

What is the most simple way to fetch a list of elements using PHP PDO? There are so many fetch and fetch parameters that I'm not sure which is the right one.

Table Users

```
| id | username | age |
-----------------------
| 5  |  Joey    | 33  |
| 6  | Terry    | 44  |
| 7  | Billy    | 44  |
```

Query

```
$q = "SELECT username FROM Users WHERE age = 44";
$db->prepare($q)->execute();
$res = $db->fetch??(PDO::??);
echo json_encode($res);
// Should return, ideally, {"Terry", "Billy"}
```

If I use fetchColumn I seem to just get one result. If I use fetchAll with assoc_array, well I don't want to iterate over the array if I can avoid it.

Comment: try here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770630/pdofetchall-vs-pdofetch-in-a-loop

Comment: @danjam wasn't concerned about performance, but thanks.

Comment: I have to admit performance is usually a factor in which method I choose. For resultsets that will be small I use fetchAll and for larger ones I use fetch within a while loop. Aside from that it would be personal preference I think :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $db is an instance of \PDO

```
$q = "SELECT username FROM Users WHERE age = :age";
$stmt = $db->prepare($q);
$stmt->bindParam(':age', 44, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

$objects = array();
while ($object = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    $objects[] = $object;
}

echo json_encode($objects);
```

Comment: So there's really no simple fetch statement that just returns all the matched columns? I figured that's the most basic thing MySQL is supposed to do.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php You can fetch all in the same way. MySQL has nothing to do with PDO (PDO = PHP Data Objects)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using

```
$res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
return implode(",", $res);
```