# Receiving array of values in GET request via PHP Api script

Tags: php, mysql, api

I have written an API script in PHP which receives a single value for parameter 'id' and returns the corresponding entry in db.How can I receive an array of values for 'id' and return all corresponding entries?

```
if(@$_GET["id"]){
    @$id=$_GET['id'];

    $where="where id=".$id;
 }else{
    $id=0;
    $where="";
 }
```

PS I have only started working with PHP.

Comment: then start with **prepared statements with paraeters** to prevent **sql injection** see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: have you created a instance of PDO or mysqli, then you can use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30354280/php-pdo-method-to-fetch-simple-list-of-matched-elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is bad practice to suppress error using **@**, instead, check it's existence with **isset()** function.
Like this

```
if(isset($_GET["id"])){
           $id = $_GET["id"];
}
```

or

```
$id = isset($_GET["id"])? $_GET["id"] : 0;
```

Now, if your **id** post variable as an array of values. You can collect them using **foreach**, like this

```
if(isset($_GET["id"])){
   foreach($_GET["id"] as $id){
       echo $id; // use it as you want.
}
    }
```

I am assuming your id post variable and is a single dimension array.