# Load another php code on Model dialog

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I  have an `access.php` code which display all the read records:

```
        <div class='tile-body'>

          <table id='access' class='display responsive nowrap' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
             <thead>
                 <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>First name</th>
                  <th>Last name</th>
                  <th>Therapist</th>
                  <th>Postcode</th>
                  <th>Access Type</th>
                  <th>Access Code</th>
                  <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
             </thead>
            <tbody>

            <?php


                      // include database connection
                      include 'include/database.php';

                          $action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : "";

                          // if it was redirected from delete.php
                          if($action=='deleted'){
                              echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>Record was deleted.</div>";
                          }

                                // select all data
                          $query = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, therapist, postcode, access_type, code FROM access ORDER BY id DESC";
                          $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
                          $stmt->execute();

                          // this is how to get number of rows returned
                          $num = $stmt->rowCount();

                          //check if more than 0 record found
                          if($num>0){     


                                  // retrieve our table contents
                                  // fetch() is faster than fetchAll()
                                  // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770630/pdofetchall-vs-pdofetch-in-a-loop
                                  while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                                      // extract row
                                      // this will make $row['firstname'] to
                                      // just $firstname only
                                      extract($row);

                                      // creating new table row per record
                                      echo "<tr>";
                                          echo "<td>{$id}</td>";
                                          echo "<td>{$firstname}</td>";
                                          echo "<td>{$lastname}</td>";
                                          echo "<td>{$therapist}</td>";
                                          echo "<td>{$postcode}</td>";
                                          echo "<td>{$access_type}</td>";
                                          echo "<td>{$code}</td>";
                                          echo "<td>";
                                              // read one record 
                                              echo "<a href='access_one.php?id={$id}' class='btn btn-info m-r-1em'>Read</a>";

                                              // we will use this links on next part of this post
                                              echo "<a href='upd_access.php?id={$id}' class='btn btn-primary m-r-1em'>Edit</a>";

                                              // we will use this links on next part of this post
                                              echo "<a href='del_access.php?id={$id}' class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</a>";
                                          echo "</td>";
                                      echo "</tr>";
                                  }

                          } 

              ?>

       </tbody>                            
     </table>
    </div>
```

Now, I have an `edit_access.php` that opens on the next page, but what I wanted to do is to load it model dialog. Have tried different options but the id's of each road are not popping up. I am only getting the same edit pop up for records.

```
    <div class="container w-420 p-15 bg-white mt-40 text-center">

    <?php if(isset($status)){ echo $status; }?>

    <!-- validation error -->
    <?php
    //check for any errors
    if(isset($error)){
      foreach($error as $error){
        echo "<br/>";
        echo '<span class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable" text-align="center">'.$error.'</span>';
        echo "<br/>";
      }
    }
    //if(isset($msg)){ echo $msg;}
    ?>

    <h2 class="text-light text-greensea">Update Record</h2>


    <?php

         error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

        // include database connection
        include 'include/database.php';
    // get passed parameter value, in this case, the record ID
    // isset() is a PHP function used to verify if a value is there or not
    $id=isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : die('ERROR: Record ID not found.');

    // check if form was submitted
    if($_POST){

        try{

            // write update query
            // in this case, it seemed like we have so many fields to pass and 
            // it is better to label them and not use question marks
            $query = "UPDATE access SET firstname=:firstname, lastname=:lastname, therapist=:therapist, postcode=:postcode, access_type=:access_type, code=:code WHERE id = :id";

            // prepare query for excecution
            $stmt = $con->prepare($query);


            // posted values
            $firstname=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['firstname']));
            $lastname=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['lastname']));
            $therapist=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['therapist']));
            $postcode=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['postcode']));
            $access_type=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['access_type']));
            $code=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['code']));

            // bind the parameters
            // bind the parameters
            $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
            $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
            $stmt->bindParam(':therapist', $therapist);
            $stmt->bindParam(':postcode', $postcode);      
            $stmt->bindParam(':access_type', $access_type);       
            $stmt->bindParam(':code', $code);      
            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);


            // Execute the query
            if($stmt->execute()){
                echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>Record was updated.</div>";
            }else{
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Unable to update record. Please try again.</div>";
            }

        }

        // show errors
        catch(PDOException $exception){
            die('ERROR: ' . $exception->getMessage());
        }
    }
    ?>

    <form name="update" class="form-validation mt-20" novalidate="" action="upd_access.php?id=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($id); ?>" method="post" autocomplete='off'>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control underline-input" value='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($firstname, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>' placeholder='firstname'></td>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control underline-input" value='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($lastname, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>' placeholder='lastname'></td>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="therapist" class="form-control underline-input" value='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($therapist, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>' placeholder='therapist'></td>
      </div>

      <?php $access_type = $access_type; ?>
      <div class="form-group ">
        <label for="work status">Access Type</label>
        <div name="access_type" value='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($access_type, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>'>

          <label class="checkbox-inline checkbox-custom">
            <input type="checkbox" name="access_type" <?php if (isset($access_type) && $access_type == "Keysafe") echo "checked"; ?> value="Keysafe"><i></i>Keysafe
        </label>
          <label class="checkbox-inline checkbox-custom">
            <input type="checkbox" name="access_type" <?php if (isset($access_type) && $access_type == "keylog") echo "checked"; ?> value="keylog"><i></i>Keylog
        </label>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="code" class="form-control underline-input" value='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($code, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>' placeholder='access code'></td>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="postcode" class="form-control underline-input" value='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($postcode, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>' placeholder='postcode'></td>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group text-left mt-20">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Update Access</button>
        <a href="access.php">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-greensea b-0 br-2 mr-5">Back To Record</button>
        </a>
      </div>

    </form>



    </div>
    <!-- end of container -->
```

Any help please?

Comment: can you please create a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that focuses on the actual problem?

Comment: K I will try just driving now. emergency. thanks