# Can't fetch query result in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to fetch some data from a mysql database. I'm using PDO + prepared statements and then fetching the result as an associative array. The data is not being displayed.

```
<?php

try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM bestsellers");
    $stmt->execute();


    while ($result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<tr class="bestseller-game-template">';
        echo '<td class="col-sm-3">' . $result["title"] . '</td>';
        echo '<td class="col-sm-3">' . $result["genre"] . '</td>';
        echo '<td class="col-sm-3">' . $result["rating"] . '</td>';
        echo '<td class="col-sm-3">' . $result["price"] . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: And what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Hint: [`setFetchMode`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php) doesn't fetch, it just tells it *how to* fetch. Please read the documentation carefully before just smashing a function.

Comment: There is not really a reason for you to prepare this query, as there are no parameters by the way

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton It might have some later. A naked `SELECT * FROM table` is bound to need a `LIMIT ?` eventually.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I'm just saying it's not a big deal, and it's better to be *prepared* for the future than to have someone jam in `$_POST['limit']` for lack of a better place to do it and wreck everything.

Comment: This may be microoptimization, but is preparing any slower than straight executing? @tadman

Comment: Or you can try `while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {...}`

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I bet if you benchmarked it you'd have a hard time telling. The `prepare` function doesn't do much with emulation turned on, which is the default.

Answer (score 0):

When setting up your PDO, set Fetch mode there:

```
$opt = [
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
        ];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
```

Then fetch your data using fetch();

```
while($result = $stmt->fetch()){

                        echo ' <tr class="bestseller-game-template">';
                        echo '<td class="col-sm-3">'.$result["title"].'</td>';
                        echo '<td class="col-sm-3">'.$result["genre"].'</td>';
                        echo '<td class="col-sm-3">'.$result["rating"].'</td>';
                        echo '<td class="col-sm-3">'.$result["price"].'</td>';
                        echo '</tr>';
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check [here](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php) for more information
try this:

```
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while($result = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo ' <tr class="bestseller-game-template">';
    echo '<td class="col-sm-3">'.$result["title"].'</td>';
    echo '<td class="col-sm-3">'.$result["genre"].'</td>';
    echo '<td class="col-sm-3">'.$result["rating"].'</td>';
    echo '<td class="col-sm-3">'.$result["price"].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As already posted by the other users, [`PDOStatement::setFetchMode`](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php) only sets the **default** fetch mode for a prepared statement. It must be one of the `PDO::FETCH_*` constants, as described in the documentation for [PDOStatement::fetch](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetch.php).

In order to fetch records from a db table you can call `fetch()` as part of a `while` statement, or directly call `fetchAll()`.

- Technically, the `fetch()` method is used to fetch only one record. But, by applying the `while` statement, you are telling the PHP engine to fetch a new record in each iteration step.
- Comparing with `fetch()`, the `fetchAll()` method is designed to fetch multiple records at once. [A test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770630/pdofetchall-vs-pdofetch-in-a-loop) says, that "*it's faster, but requires more memory*". It's up to you to decide, if the test convinces you.

Anyway, since you are trying to fetch multiple records, I recommend using the `fetchAll` method. My personal reason for the choice is, that this way the use of a `while` statement is avoided. I always try to completely avoid `while` statements in my codes, because they can produce infinite loops. That doesn't mean though, that they shouldn't be used by you. But use them with care.

Now, the first parameter of the `fetchAll()` method is `fetch_style`. It corresponds exactly to the parameter of the `setFetchMode()` and to the first parameter of the `fetch()` method. So, again, read the parameters list of [PDOStatement::fetch](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetch.php) in detail, so you know which values it can take.

Also, I would recommend you to try to separate fetching codes from the presentation ones. Fetch all data that you need in arrays and later iterate through them as usual, in order to formatted-display the results. And try to avoid building HTML elements from PHP code, if possible.

At last, here is a very good PDO tutorial: [(The only proper) PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo).

Good luck!

```
<?php
try {
    // Connect to db.
    $conn = new PDO(
            'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=books;charset=utf8'
            , 'yourusername'
            , 'yourpassword'
            , array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
            )
    );

    // Prepare and execute query.
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM bestsellers';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    // Get the result set as an associative array.
    $bestsellers = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (PDOException $exc) {
    echo $exc->getMessage();
    exit();
} catch (Exception $exc) {
    echo $exc->getMessage();
    exit();
}
?>

<table>
    <?php
    foreach ($bestsellers as $bestseller) {
        $title = $bestseller['title'];
        $genre = $bestseller['genre'];
        $rating = $bestseller['rating'];
        $price = $bestseller['price'];
        ?>
        <tr class="bestseller-game-template">
            <td class="col-sm-3">
                <?php echo $title; ?>
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-3">
                <?php echo $genre; ?>
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-3">
                <?php echo $rating; ?>
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-3">
                <?php echo $price; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```