# My api does not work and it shows no exception

Tags: php, angular, typescript, api

So I am trying to do my own API but it does not work for some reason and I have no exception shown so I cannot understand why.

Here is my code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/an20z.png)

**database page**

```
    // specify your own database credentials
    private $host = "**************";
    private $db_name = "***********";
    private $username = "**********";
    private $password = "***********";
    public $conn;

    // get the database connection
    public function getConnection(){

        $this->conn = null;

        try{
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
            $this->conn->exec("set names utf8");
        }catch(PDOException $exception){
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }
}
?>
```

**create page**

```
<?php
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

// get database connection
include_once '../config/database.php';

// instantiate product object
include_once '../object/department.php';

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

$department = new Department($db);

// get posted data
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

// set employee property values
$department->name = $data->name;
$department->location = $data->location;

// create the department
if($department->create()){
    echo '{';
        echo '"message": "Department was created."';
    echo '}';
}

// if unable to create the department, tell the user
else{
    echo '{';
        echo '"message": "Unable to create department."';
    echo '}';
}
?>
```

**delete page**

```
<?php
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");


// include database and object file
include_once '../config/database.php';
include_once '../object/department.php';

// get database connection
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

// prepare department object
$department = new Department($db);

// get department id
// set department id to be deleted
$department->id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : die();

// delete the department
if($department->delete()){
    echo '{';
        echo '"message": "Department was deleted."';
    echo '}';
}

// if unable to delete the department
else{
    echo '{';
        echo '"message": "Unable to delete object."';
    echo '}';
}

?>
```

**readone page**

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: access");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header('Content-Type: application/json');

// include database and object files
include_once '../config/database.php';
include_once '../object/department.php';

// get database connection
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

// prepare product object
$department = new Department($db);

// set ID property of product to be edited
$department->id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : die();

// read the details of product to be edited
$department->readOne();

// create array
$department_arr = array(
    "id" =>  $department->id,
    "name" => $department->name,
    "location" => $department->location


);

// make it json format
print_r(json_encode($department_arr));
?>
```

**read page**

```
<?php
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

// include database and object files
include_once '../config/database.php';
include_once '../object/department.php';

// instantiate database and employee object
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

// initialize object
$department = new Department($db);

// query products
$stmt = $department->read();
$num = $stmt->rowCount();

// check if more than 0 record found
if($num>0){

    // department array
    $department_arr=array();
    //$department_arr["records"]=array();

    // retrieve our table contents

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        // extract row
        // this will make $row['name'] to
        // just $name only
        extract($row);

        $employee_item=array(
            "id" => intval($id),
            "name" => $name,
            "location" => $location

        );

        array_push($department_arr, $department_item);
    }

    echo json_encode($department_arr);
}

else{
    echo json_encode(
        array("message" => "No departments found.")
    );
}
?>
```

**search page**

```
<?php
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

// include database and object files
include_once '../config/database.php';
include_once '../object/department.php';

// instantiate database and employee object
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

// initialize object
$department = new Department($db);

// get keywords
$keywords=isset($_GET["s"]) ? $_GET["s"] : "";

// query departments
$stmt = $department->search($keywords);
$num = $stmt->rowCount();

// check if more than 0 record found
if($num>0){

    // employees array
    $department_arr=array();
    //$department_arr["records"]=array();

    // retrieve our table contents
    // fetch() is faster than fetchAll()
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770630/pdofetchall-vs-pdofetch-in-a-loop
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        // extract row
        // this will make $row['name'] to
        // just $name only
        extract($row);

        $employee_item=array(
            "id" => $id,
            "name" => $name,
            "location" => $location

        );

        array_push($department_arr, $department_item);
    }

    echo json_encode($department_arr);
}

else{
    echo json_encode(
        array("message" => "No departments found.")
    );
}
?>
```

**update page**

```
<?php
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

// include database and object files
include_once '../config/database.php';
include_once '../object/department.php';

// get database connection
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

// prepare product object
$department = new Department($db);

// get id of product to be edited
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

// set ID property of product to be edited
$department->id = $data->id;

// set product property values
$department->name = $data->name;
$department->location = $data->location;


// update the department
if($product->update()){
    echo '{';
        echo '"message": "Department was updated."';
    echo '}';
}

// if unable to update the department, tell the user
else{
    echo '{';
        echo '"message": "Unable to update department."';
    echo '}';
}
?>
```

**department page**

```
    // database connection and table name
    private $conn;
    private $table_name = "departments";

    // object properties
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $location;



    // constructor with $db as database connection
    public function __construct($db){
        $this->conn = $db;
    }
// read department
function read(){

    // select all query
    $query = "SELECT
                 d.id, d.name, d.location,
            FROM
                " . $this->table_name . " d
            ORDER BY
                d.id";

    // prepare query statement
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    // execute query
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt;
}

// read one
function readOne(){

    // query to read single record
    $query = "SELECT
                 d.id, d.name, d.location
            FROM
                " . $this->table_name . " d
            WHERE
                d.id = ?
            LIMIT
                0,1";

    // prepare query statement
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );

    // bind id of department to be updated
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->id);

    // execute query
    $stmt->execute();

    // get retrieved row
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // set values to object properties
    $this->name = $row['name'];
    $this->location = $row['location'];

}
function create(){

    // query to insert record
    $query = "INSERT INTO
                " . $this->table_name . "
            SET
                name=:name,location=:location";

    // prepare query
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    // sanitize
    $this->name=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->name));
    $this->location=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->location));



    // bind values
    $stmt->bindParam(":name", $this->name);
    $stmt->bindParam(":location", $this->location);



    // execute query
    if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}
// delete the department
function delete(){

    // delete query
    $query = "DELETE FROM " . $this->table_name . " WHERE id = ?";

    // prepare query
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    // sanitize

    // bind id of record to delete
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->id);

    // execute query
    if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}
// search department
function search($keywords){

    // select all query
    $query = "SELECT
                 d.id, d.name, d.location
            FROM
                " . $this->table_name . " d
            WHERE
                d.name LIKE ?
            ORDER BY
                d.id ";

    // prepare query statement
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    // sanitize
    $keywords=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($keywords));
    $keywords = "%{$keywords}%";

    // bind
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $keywords);

    // execute query
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt;
}
// update the department
function update(){

    // update query
    $query = "UPDATE
                " . $this->table_name . "
            SET
                name = :name,
                location = :location,

            WHERE
                id = :id";

    // prepare query statement
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    // sanitize
    $this->name=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->name));
    $this->location=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->location));


    // bind new values
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $this->name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':location', $this->location);


    // execute the query
    if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
}
```

**department service page**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Departments } from './departments';
import { Department } from './department';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DepartmentService {


    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    dep : Department[] = Departments;
    private depReadOne = 'http://i378011.hera.fhict.nl/api_Web/department/read_one.php?id=';
    private depRead = 'http://i378011.hera.fhict.nl/api_Web/department/read.php';
    private depDelete = 'http://i378011.hera.fhict.nl/api_Web/department/delete.php?id=';
    private depSearch = 'http://i378011.hera.fhict.nl/api_Web/department/search.php?s=';
    private depAdd = 'i378011.hera.fhict.nl/api_Web/department/create.php';

  //  getDepartments(): Observable<Department[]>{
  //    return of (this.dep);
  //  }

  //  getDepartment(id: number): Observable<Department>{
  //    return of (this.dep.find(department => department.id === id));
//    }

    getDep(id:number):Observable<Department>{
      return this.http.get<Department>(this.depReadOne + id);
        }
    getDepByName(name:string) : Observable<Department>{
      return of (this.dep.find(department => department.name === name))
    }

    getDepartmentName(name: string): Observable<Department>{
      return of(this.dep.find(department => department.name === name));
    }

    getDeps():Observable<Department[]>{
    return this.http.get<Department[]>(this.depRead);
    }



    deleteDep(id:number):Observable<Department>{
    return this.http.get<Department>(this.depDelete + id);
    }
    searchDeps(s: string):Observable<Department[]>{
    return this.http.get<Department[]>(this.depSearch + s);
    }




    updateDepartment(newDepartment: Department): void{
        console.log (this.dep);
      let oldDep = this.dep.find(department => department.id === newDepartment.id)
       oldDep = newDepartment;
      console.log (this.dep);
    }

    addDepartment (name:string, location:string): void {
        console.log (this.dep);
        this.dep.push(new Department(name,location));
        console.log (this.dep);
    }


  //  deleteDepartment(department: Department): void{
  //    console.log (this.dep);

         this.dep.forEach( (item, index) => {
       if(item === department) this.dep.splice(index,1);});
        console.log (this.dep);
    }

  }
```

All I get is a blank page in the browser and I have no exceptions shown. When I click right button on the mouse and then inspect I get this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4Sqk.png)

Comment: **Way too much code** to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a **[Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**
 and [TAKE THE TOUR](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well the error message is pretty clear. At the end of your department service page you call `this.dep.forEach` but this.dep is undefined.
At the top you call `dep : Department[] = Departments;` (which you would normally do inside of the constructor). Maybe it will work, if you move this code inside of your constructor, otherwise you should check what you are importing from `import { Departments } from './departments';`