# How do I correct duplicated json array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code that reads data from a mysql database. Unfortunately I dont seem to find a way of removing this `"status": {`

Here is the code snippet

```
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
  
// database connection will be here

// include database and object files
include_once '../config/database.php';
include_once '../objects/status.php';
  
// instantiate database and status object
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();
  
// initialize object
$status = new Status($db);
  
// query status
$stmt = $status->read();
$num = $stmt->rowCount();
  
// check if more than 0 record found
if($num>0){
  
    // status array
    $status_arr=array();
    $status_arr["status"]=array();
  
    // retrieve our table contents
    // fetch() is faster than fetchAll()
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770630/pdofetchall-vs-pdofetch-in-a-loop
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        // extract row
        // this will make $row['name'] to
        // just $name only
        extract($row);
  
        $status_item = array(
            "id" => $status_id,
            "name" => html_entity_decode($status_name),
            "created" => $status_created,
            "modified" => $status_modified,
            "state" => $status_state
        );

        array_push($status_arr["status"], $status_item);
    }
  
    // set response code - 200 OK
    http_response_code(200);
  
    // show status data in json format

    echo json_encode(
        array("response_code" => 0, "response_message" => "Request processed successfully", "status" => $status_arr)
    );
}
else{
  
    // set response code - 404 Not found
    http_response_code(404);
  
    // tell the user no status found
    echo json_encode(
        array("response_code" => 1, "response_message" => "No status found.")
    );
```

Which outputs this:

```
{
    "response_code": 0,
    "response_message": "Request processed successfully",
    "status": {
        "status": [
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "Inactive",
                "created": "2020-08-24 17:43:52",
                "modified": "2020-08-24 13:43:52",
                "state": "Active"
            },
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Active",
                "created": "2020-08-24 12:44:49",
                "modified": "2020-08-24 05:44:49",
                "state": "Active"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The desired output is:

```
{
        "response_code": 0,
        "response_message": "Request processed successfully",
            "status": [
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "name": "Inactive",
                    "created": "2020-08-24 17:43:52",
                    "modified": "2020-08-24 13:43:52",
                    "state": "Active"
                },
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "name": "Active",
                    "created": "2020-08-24 12:44:49",
                    "modified": "2020-08-24 05:44:49",
                    "state": "Active"
                }
            ]
    }
```

Note that in the desired output should not have  `"status": {}` but should only have  `"status": []`. What modification should i do to the above provided code?

Comment: Did you try to remove this line

$status_arr["status"]=array();

?

Comment: And also edit from array_push($status_arr["status"], $status_item); to array_push($status_arr, $status_item);

Comment: @SergioRinaudo this doesnt help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo json_encode(
  array(
    "response_code" => 0,
    "response_message" => "Request processed successfully",
    "status" => $status_arr["status"]
  )
);
```

Comment: Thank you brother...sorts my issue. I have marked this as an answer to help any other person who might come across it