# Link problem between angular 11 component and data from server

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

i had this problem  when i connects the api php with the service in angular to get data from the data base .and i dont know if the problem is in the service or in the component.ts or in the html part .
that's why i share you my code to help me.

the problem is :

ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

By the way I got the data coming from server when I do console.log () but it does not arrive in the list.

carservice.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Car } from './car';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CarService {
  baseUrl = 'http://localhost/api/car';
  
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  }
  
  
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAll(): Observable<Car[]> {
    return this.http.get<Car[]>(this.baseUrl+'/read.php/')
    .pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    )
  }   
}
```

voiturecomponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Car } from 'app/car';
import { CarService } from 'app/car.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-voiture',
  templateUrl: './voiture.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./voiture.component.css']
})
export class VoitureComponent implements OnInit {
  cars : Car[] = [] ;


  constructor(private carService: CarService, private router:Router) { }

  onBackButtonClick() :  void {
    this.router.navigate(['/ajout-car']) ;  
  }

  
    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.carService.getAll().subscribe((data: Car[])=>{
        console.log(data);
        
        this.cars = data ;
       
      })  
    }
}
```

voiturecomponent.html

```
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card">
                 

                  
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="card-header">
                  <h4 class="title" ><strong> Liste Voiture </strong></h4>
                </div></div>
              
                <div class="card-body">
                  <span type="button" 
                        class="btn btn-fill tn-secondary pull-right"
                        (click)=onBackButtonClick() >
                        <i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        Ajouter Voiture 
                  </span>
                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>

                <br>
      
 <div id="theList"> 

                    
  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
  <table class="table table-bordered " >
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Série</th>
      <th>Model</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    
   <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let car of cars ">
      <td>{{car.id}}</td>
      <td>{{car.model}}</td>
      <td>{{car.serie}}</td>
      <td>

   
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-fill btn-warning btn-sm btn-space">
          <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button"  class="btn btn-info btn-fill btn-danger btn-sm btn-space" >
          <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>
    

      </td>
     </tr> 
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
</div>
 </div>
</div>
</div> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I hope that you can help me .

Comment: The error indicates that the data you’re trying to loop through is not actually an array. Show your API response (probably an object instead of an array)

Answer (score 1):

this is my api

```
<?php
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
  
// database connection will be here
// include database and object files
include_once '../connect.php';
include_once '../objects/car.php';
  
// instantiate database and product object
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();
  
// initialize object
$car = new Car ($db);
  
// read car will be here
// query car
$stmt = $car->read();
$num = $stmt->rowCount();
  
// check if more than 0 record found
if($num>0){
  
    // products array
    $car_arr=array();
    $car_arr["records"]=array();
  
    // retrieve our table contents
    // fetch() is faster than fetchAll()
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770630/pdofetchall-vs-pdofetch-in-a-loop
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        // extract row
        // this will make $row['name'] to
        // just $name only
        extract($row);
  
        $car_item=array(
            "id" => $id,
            "model" => $model,
            "serie" => $serie,
        );
  
        array_push($car_arr["records"], $car_item);
    }
  
    // set response code - 200 OK
    http_response_code(200);
  
    // show cars data in json format
    echo json_encode($car_arr);
}
  
// no car found will be here
else{
  
    // set response code - 404 Not found
    http_response_code(404);
  
    // tell the user no car found
    echo json_encode(
        array("message" => "No cars found.")
    );
}
?>
```

```
<?php
class Car {
  
    // database connection and table name
    private $conn;
    private $table_name = "cars";
  
    // object properties
    public $id;
    public $model;
    public $serie;
  
  
    // constructor with $db as database connection
    public function __construct($db){
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

  // read cars
  function read() {
  
    // select all query
    $query = "SELECT
                 p.id, p.model, p.serie
            FROM
                " . $this->table_name . " p ;
            ORDER BY
              
            p.id DESC";
  
    // prepare query statement
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
  
    // execute query
    $stmt->execute();
  
    return $stmt;
   }

}
```

Comment: your api is fine on your angular service and component test out with any type maybe your type not matching

Comment: how can i making it matched , can you help me ??

Comment: problem solved thank you for your answers.