# Wrong database query?

Tags: php, mysql, api

I'm learning and atm writing API with PHP and MySql. It's about tasks and tags exercise.
I have this problem - when i read the database where task and tags are connected,JSON shows all data but + id of the tags which i don't need, because are already on the json data.

***This is the read method with query.***

```
function read(){

    // select all query
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `task_tag`
    INNER JOIN task ON task_tag.id_task =  task.id
    INNER JOIN tag ON task_tag.id_tag  = tag.id";

    // prepare query statement
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    // execute query
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt;
    
}
```

**This is where i call data**

```
// products array
$tasks_arr["task_tag"]=array();
$index = 0;
// retrieve our table contents
// fetch() is faster than fetchAll()
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770630/pdofetchall-vs-pdofetch-in-a-loop
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    $tasks_arr[$index] = $row;
    $index++;
}

// set response code - 200 OK
http_response_code(200);

// show products data in json format
echo json_encode($tasks_arr);
}
```

**This is only 1 data i'll show. The others have the same id which i don't know where it comes**

```
"task_tag": \[\],
"0": {
**"id": "2",** // This is the id that match "id_tag" in every data showen.
"id_task": "5",
"id_tag": "2",
"task_name": "Buy beer",
"tag_name": "Alcohol drinks",
"color": "#FA8072"
},
```

Comment: What do you want; or not want? Maybe changing the `*` to the columns you want answers the question?

Comment: I need to show me the json object without this id. But when i change * to columns , shows me only id_task and id_tag. Doesnt show task_name,tag_name and color

Answer (score 0):

You have a column `id` in more than one table. Your query fetches all of these columns, because you used `SELECT *`.

An SQL result can have more than one column of the same name. That's no problem.

But a PHP associative array can only store one value for a given key.

As PDO maps the query result into an associative array, it overwrites the `id` key in the associative array with the `id` column of the `tag` table. This is arbitrary, it could have picked one of the other tables, but in this case it happened to pick the `tag` table.

If you want to fix this, don't use `SELECT *`. Instead, name each of the columns you want the query to return. If a given column name appears in more than one table, give it an alias so the PDO query result can map it into a distinct key in the associative array.

Comment: I need to show me only both id and both names:

"id_task": "5",
"id_tag": "2",
"task_name": "Buy beer",
"tag_name": "Alcohol drinks",
"color": "#FA8072"

Something like this